# The method 'Amplify' isn't defined for the type '_MyAppState'. -FlutterAmplify

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, flutteramplify

I've just started learning AWS Amplify and followed the step given in https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-flutter-app-amplify/module-two/ to initialize Amplify in my flutter project. But I'm getting *The method 'Amplify' isn't defined for the type '_MyAppState'* error when I'm trying to integrate Amplify (with statement **final _amplify = Amplify();**) in my App.

Below is my main.dart file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './amplifyconfiguration.dart';
import 'package:amplify_core/amplify_core.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _amplify = Amplify();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureAmplify();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  void _configureAmplify() async {
    try {
      await _amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
      print('Successfully configured Amplify ');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Could not configure Amplify ☠️');
    }
  }
}
```

Amplify dependency that I have imported in pubspec.yaml

```
amplify_core: '<1.0.0'
```

amplifyconfiguration.dart

```
const amplifyconfig = ''' {
   "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
   "Version": "1.0"
}''';
```

Also when I run "Amplify console", I'm getting **App with id: xxxxxxxxxx not found**

Comment: Hi mate, where did you get the amplifyconfig ?
I'm trying to implement Cognito login in flutter, but i can't find the amplifyconfig documents. 
Thanks you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/274
amplify_core is now renamed to amplify_flutter so you need to change

```
amplify_core: '<1.0.0'
```

to

```
amplify_flutter: '<1.0.0'
```

In addition, as Amplify class is a static singleton now, you don't need to instantiate it, so you can remove this line:

```
final _amplify = Amplify();
```

Comment: Also need to replace
import 'package:amplify_core/amplify_core.dart'
with
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify.dart'